# Access Link Generated Inside a Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I started a docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -i -p 8989:8989 -p 8888:8888 -v /Users/sroche/FISHDATA/tiff_stacks:/home/neuroglancer_user/test_data -t openmind/neuroglancer:1.0 jupyter notebook --ip='0.0.0.0'
```

This creates a container running jupyter notebook and neuroglancer. These specifics are not too important, but may be helpful.

I have a notebook inside the container that generates a link, and this link is supposed to allow me to use my browser to view images at the address in the link. However, I am not allowed from connecting to the link, with the response:

[image: this site can't be reached error]

(I am simply putting the link into a Chrome browser)

The link I am trying to access looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:42071/v/.../
```

How can I connect to a link that is generated within a Docker container?

Comment: e you tried accessing 0.0.0.0:8888 or 127.0.0.1:8888 ?

Comment: Ok, it seems like you know the final port (42071), however, in your docker command, you map 8888:8888, is that correct or mistake? On what port should the server (inside docker) run? If indeed it has to be port 42071, then change your command 8888:8888 to 8888:42071. If it still fails, try the links suggested above, in combination with localhost:8888/v/.../